# attaching a file to a message

Tags: c#, sendmail, email-attachments, mailmessage

I created an html using string builder and placed it in the current directory

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("../../Data.html");
```

Now I want to attach this file and send it as a mail. How can I add this as an attachment to my email?

This is what I do more or less with a regular html message. How can I add the file as an attachment to it?

```
public bool sendMailAttachment(string to, string from, string subject, string body, string attachment)
    {
        bool k = false;
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client;
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = body;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "staging.itmaniax.co.za";
            //client.Port = 25;

            //****
            //client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);

            k = true;

        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exe.ToString());
        }
        return k;
```

Comment: There is an Attachments property on the MailMessage object....

Comment: Before creating new questions, please look back at your previous questions and accept any answers that worked for you... for instance you asked a *very* similar question yesterday, which was answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357877/trying-to-send-a-basic-email-to-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you don't dispose of that attachment properly, it will keep the file open indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go,
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10828/Sending-Email-with-attachment-in-ASP-NET-using-SMT

The above answer was just a google away.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CodeProject article that goes over adding an attachment to a `MailMessage`.  I'd consider taking a look at that first, and returning with any questions presented.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10828/Sending-Email-with-attachment-in-ASP-NET-using-SMT

Here's some MSDN reading as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx